# Table-Valued Function as IQueryable in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Table-Valued function which I would like to use as an `IQueryable` in a LINQ statement. I have created the following in my `DbContext` class:

```
[DbFunction("dbo","MyTableValuedFunction")]
public virtual IQueryable<MyClass> MyFunction(string keyword)
{
    var keywordsParam = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("keywords", typeof(string))
    {
        Value = keyword
    };

    return (this as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        .CreateQuery<MyClass>("dbo.MyTableValuedFunction(@keywords)", keywordsParam);
}
```

The result of `dbo.MyTableValuedFunction(@keywords)` match an existing class "`MyClass`". An example of how I'd like to use this function:

```
MyClass example = (from a in dbContext.MyClass
                  join b in dbContext.MyFunction("exampleKeyword")
                      on a.Id equals b.Id
                  join c in dbContext.MyOtherClass
                      on a.SomeId equals c.Id
                  select a);
```

...but enumerating this `IEnumerable` throws an exception:
`'dbo.MyTableValuedFunction' cannot be resolved into a valid type or function.`

I have tried reducing the function to just one column, and changing the type to `<int>`, but this doesn't work, so I am not sure what is happening here; it's like the TVF is not being correctly found/recognised/used?

I have also tried following https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Table-valued_function and on the off-chance there's some subtle difference, I create the function with:
    `[Function(FunctionType.TableValuedFunction, "MyTableValuedFunction", Schema = "dbo")]`

...but I run into exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First if you used [this](https://github.com/moozzyk/CodeFirstFunctions) extension, you should write following code according to your code:

```
[DbFunction("dbo","MyTableValuedFunction")]
public virtual IQueryable<MyClass> MyFunction(string keyword)
{
    var keywordsParam = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("keywords", typeof(string))
    {
        Value = keyword
    };

    return (this as System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
        .CreateQuery<MyClass>("[Your DbContext Name].MyFunction(@keywords)", keywordsParam);
}
```

According to the extension codes, the EF uses conventions to translate the C# syntax into sql syntax. for this reason, you should register your functions in dbContext first as the link mentioned.